# PostgreSQL effective way to store a list of IDs

Tags: postgresql

In my PostgreSQL I have two tables `board` and `cards` tables with `OneToMany` relationship between them(one `board` can have a multiple `cards`).

User can hold a few cards on the board. In order to implement this functionality typically I would created another table called for example `cards_on_hold` with `OneToMany` relationship and placed cards on hold IDs into this table. In order to fetch this data for board I'd use JOIN between `board` and `cards_on_hold`.

Is there any more effective way in PostgreSQL to store cards on hold IDs ? Maybe for example some feature to store this list inline in `board` table ? I'll need to use this IDs list later in `IN` SQL clause in order to filter card set.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Postgres does support arrays of integers (assuming your ids are integers):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

However manipulating that data is a bit hard compared to a separate table. For example with a separate table you can put a uniqueness guarantee so that you won't have duplicates of ids (assuming you'd want that). To achieve the same thing with an array you would have to create a stored procedure to detect duplicates (on insert for example). That would be hard (if possible at all) to be as efficient as simple `unique` constraint. Not to mention that you lose consistency guarantee because you can't put foreign key constraint on such array.

So in general conisistency would be an issue with inline list. At the same time I doubt you would get any noticable performance gain. After all arrays should not be used as an "aggregated foreign key" IMHO.

All in all: I suggest you stick to a separate table.